# Entity design suggestion

Tags: java, entity

I need to design an entity of some kind of **Coupon** which has a due date property for usage. The problem is the due date can be a specific date assigned or calculated from a period, like 60 days, after the user gets the coupon. So my question is how can I design an entity of Coupon to satisfy this requirement such that I can easily get the due date of different kind of coupons? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Here is an example. Right now I have 2 entities, `User` and `Coupon`, and a relation entity of these 2 object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // ....

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "coupon")
public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Date dueDate;

    private Integer periodDays;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_coupon")
public class UserCoupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, optional = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, optional = false)
    private Coupon coupon;

    private Date dueDate;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public UserCoupon(User user, Coupon coupon) {
        this.user = user;
        this.coupon = coupon;
        if (coupon.getDueDate() != null) {
            this.dueDate = coupon.getDueDate();
        } else if (coupon.getPeriodDays() != null) {
            this.dueDate = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), coupon.getPeriodDays());
        }
    }

    // ....
}
```

The `dueDate` and `periodDays` filled in the `Coupon` class are mutualyl exclusive by business logic. That is to say, a coupon has either a fixed due date or an integer property (`periodDays`) for calculating the due date once a user gets the coupon.

Right now I can put both 2 fields in the `Coupon` class, but when I need to set the `dueDate` field in the `UserCoupon` class, I found it a little tedious and inconvenient to check which of the mutually exclusive fields in the `Coupon` class is `null` and finally calculate out the `dueDate` in the `UserCoupon` class (see `UserCoupon` class constructor).

Therefore, I want to know if there's some good entity design strategy which can avoid tedious field null check when calculating due date and make sure the 2 fields in the `Coupon` class are mutually exclusive at the same time as they are mutually exclusive by business logic and not by code.

Comment: You question is a bit broad. Perhaps add your attempt (even in pseudo-code) to show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @user1803551 I have added some code and detailed explanation for my question. Hope it's clear for you. :)

Comment: Can't you create a method in `Coupon` that calculates the `dueDate` value based on the `dueDate` and `periodDays`, whatever your logic for doing that is?

Comment: @user1803551 I add a constructor to initiate the `UserCoupon`object from `User` and `Coupon`, in which it contains the calculation logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just put the calculation logic in the `Coupon` class:

```
public class Coupon {

    private Date dueDate;

    private Integer periodDays;

    public Date getExpirationDate() { // name this whatever makes sense

        // assuming you can guarantee that one and only one is null == mutually exclusive
        return (dueDate != null) ? dueDate : DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), periodDays);
    }
}
```

And then in `UserCoupon`

```
public class UserCoupon {

    private Date dueDate;

    public UserCoupon(User user, Coupon coupon) {

        dueDate = coupon.getExpirationDate();
    }
}
```

This looks clear and readable (to me), while making sense in terms of design. This is because the "expiration date" calculation depends only on the `Coupon` data, and so it should be the one to implement the logic. Another way to look at it would be: other classes don't care how the calculation is done, they just want the final result. `Coupon` "has a contract" to provide that result and so it should be responsible for it.

Comment: Wow, I just didn't realise that I could improve my code better in such a simple way. I should definitely go to review object oriented programming again. Thanks for reminding me that I just forgot encapsulation entirely. This is a good answer, however, `Coupon` class can not still guarantee that `dueDate` and `periodDays` are mutual excluded. It would be perfect that `Coupon` class can be improved to satisfy the "mutual exclusion" requirement. Thanks a lot for your time and this good answer. :)

Comment: @lute I thought that the mutual exclusion is already guaranteed externally. Since it's not, I would need to know how `Coupon` is created since that's the place where you can guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field in class Coupon to show it's valid time coupon or coupon since receive. Based on the field you have different calculation strategy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a due date and an activation date and when activated just set the due date.

Comment: Sorry that I might not understand you completely. Could you please explain it more in detail?

Comment: thinking better now, I guess is better if you map another entity/table to join User and Cupom. This can be useful if a user can have more than one cupom, in this new entity you can put a due date as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done so far. I put a due date into the joined entity/table. But I wonder how can I get the value of the due date. Because it can come from 2 different sources. One is a fixed due date specified when the coupon is created no matter what date the user get the coupon. The other is a dynamic date calculated from a fixed period days after the coupon activation, like 90 days after coupon activation. So the coupon either has a fixed due date or a period days like 90. How to arrange these 2 mutual excluded property in Coupon entity is what I got stuck.

Comment: @lute You need to detail the exact specifications in your question. Be very precise about how dates and durations work and what you need to achieve in term of functionality.